# How to return the unique elements between vectors while retaining the source vector of these unique elements?

Tags: r, list, vector, unique, data-mining

For example, I have 5 vectors in a list:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

C <- c(5,6,7,8,9)

D <- c(8,9)
```

In reality I have 100s of these vectors but I only gave 5 vectors for reproducibility.
My goal is to:

1. Identify the unique elements coming from the vectors. For example, `vector A` shouldn't return anything because all of its elements are part of `vector B`, however `vector B` does contribute with an extra unique element and that is `6`.  `Vector C` should give me `7,8,9` since `c(5,6)` were already included in `vector B`. `Vector D` should return nothing because all of its elements are part of C
2. recognize which element is unique from which vector
3. Find which vectors are subsets of other bigger vectors. For example, `vector D` is a subset of `C` and `vector A` is a subset of `vector B`.

So far the only solution I've found was:

```
Reduce(setdiff, list("my_vectors"))
```

**But** it doesn't allow me to recognize which element is unique from which vector. For example, `Reduce(setdiff, list(A,B))` would return `6`, but I would have no idea where the `6` came from ( `A` or `B`)?

My difficulty is in this being a large scale problem, I don't have 5 vectors only, I have 100s of them so I can't figure out a sustainable solution. Any tips are appreciated.

Edit: my vectors are in a list

Comment: Are the vectors in the `.GlobalEnv` or in a list?

Comment: They are in a list. So I have a list of vectors.

Comment: In your example there are not exclusive ciphers.

Comment: This is not well defined: for example A should not return anythng because B contains all elements in A, but B should return 6. However, 6 is also contained in C. So here the only truly unique element you have is 7 in C am I correct?

Comment: Exactly. It is rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

A first naive approach would be a for-loop, just to have a working solution.
The function returns a list with the unqiue elements and a dataframe, describing from which vector in the vectorList the unique elements (first appereance) are coming from.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
C <- c(5,6,7,8,9)
D <- c(8,9)

vectorList <- list(A,B,C,D)

ff <- function(vectorList) {
  uniques <- unique(vectorList[[1]])
  comingFromDf <- data.frame(values=uniques)
  comingFromDf$source <- 1
  
  for(k in 2:length(vectorList)) {
    vec <- vectorList[[k]]
    newUniques <- vec[!(vec %in% uniques)]
    if(length(newUniques)) {
      newUniques <- unique(newUniques)
      toAdd <- data.frame(values=newUniques)
      toAdd$source <- k
      comingFromDf <- rbind(comingFromDf,toAdd)
      uniques <- c(uniques,newUniques)
    }
  }
  
  list(uniqueElements = uniques,
       comingFromInfo = comingFromDf)
}

ff(vectorList)
```

I don't know how performant you need the function to be, but even with 200 vectors of length 1000 it seems to be quit fast (I don't know about your dimensions):

```
bigVectorList <- lapply(1:200, function(k) {
  sample(1:1e6,1000)
})

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff(bigVectorList),times=10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#ff(bigVectorList) 619.5148 624.8351 639.7535 633.2326 647.118 685.0387    10
```

On my machine, it took a bit more than half a second, maybe thats enough for you. Since the function only includes vectors and a dataframe, it would be quit easy to re-implement it in C++ and using Rcpp. This should be much faster than the for-loop implementation in R. Moreover, you can consider using the `accumulate`-argument in the `Reduce`-function to save the intermediate calculation-results.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data is stored like this:

```
my_vectors <- list(
  A = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  B = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  C = c(5,6,7,8,9),
  D = c(8,9)
)
```

If you use `accumulate = TRUE` to the call of `Reduce`, you get every intermediate result as well. We can use this together with `union` to build up the total set step by step (note that I set `init = c()` to make sure we start empty):

```
acc <- Reduce(union, my_vectors, init = c(), accumulate = T)
```

Then, we can take the `setdiff` of every item with this built-up list.

```
lapply(1:length(my_vectors), function(i) setdiff(my_vectors[[i]], acc[[i]]))
```

This gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[4]]
numeric(0)
```

You can apply the names of `my_vectors` later if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

`lag(accumulate(l, union))` keeps track of all the elements seen so far. The difference between this and the original list yields the newly seen elements.

```
library(tidyverse)

l <- lst(A, B, C, D)

map2(l, lag(accumulate(l, union)), setdiff)
#> $A
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> $D
#> numeric(0)
```

---

Here is an answer to your other question about finding which vectors are subsets of other bigger vectors.

`expand_grid` will get all combinations of the vectors. Filter this to find which vector is a subset of any other vector.

```
l %>%
  enframe() %>%
  expand_grid(a = ., b = .) %>%
  filter(
    a$name != b$name,
    map2_lgl(a$value, b$value, ~all(.x %in% .y))
  ) %>%
  transmute(this_vector = a$name, is_a_subset_of_this_vector = b$name)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   this_vector is_a_subset_of_this_vector
#>   <chr>       <chr>                     
#> 1 A           B                         
#> 2 D           C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you only have one truly unique element which is `7` in `C`. The below will return the unique elements as well as their memberships

```
mylist <- list("A"=A,"B"=B,"C"=C,"D"=D) #better for 100's of vectors
myres <- !unlist(lapply(1:length(mylist), function(x) unlist(mylist[x]) %in% unlist(mylist[-x])))
result <- as.numeric(unlist(mylist)[myres])
member <- sapply(mylist, function(x) result %in% x)
membername <- names(mylist[member])
result
membername
> result
 7 
> membername
[1] "C"
```